# Was the shot-on-the-ISS movie "The Challenge" ever released or is there a release date?

Tags: iss, astronauts, russian-segment

In October 2021 scenes for a movie entitled "The Challenge" were shot onboard the ISS with actor Yulia Peresild and director Klim Shipenko spending a short stay on the station.

Source: [Russian Film Crew Blasts Off As ‘The Challenge’ Set To Become First Feature To Shoot In Outer Space](https://deadline.com/2021/10/russia-film-crew-the-challenge-first-feature-shoot-outer-space-1234849794/)

[image]
Image source: [NASA](https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/iss065e454812/iss065e454812%7Eorig.jpg)

It's been over a year and I can't find any reference to a release or a release date. But I suspect this may be due to my English-centric internet searching.

Was this movie ever released, or if not yet, has a release date been announced?

Comment: Movies usually take a while to make, especially ones with special effects or that didn't have the luxury of being able to reshoot scenes that didn't work out, lol - I can imagine the edit on this was a bit fretful...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is yet to be released though trailers are already out for it.

https://www.cbr.com/the-challenge-movie-trailer/

> Dec 31, 2022 #MovieChallenge
>
> The world premiere of the trailer for the first feature film in the history of cinema and astronautics, filmed on the International Space Station.
>
> Starring: Yulia Peresild, Milos Bikovich, Vladimir Mashkov, Oleg Novitsky, Anton Shkaplerov, Pyotr Dubrov, Elena Valyushkina, Varvara Volodina and others.
>
> The space drama "The Challenge" directed by Klim Shipenko is in all cinemas from April 12.

Sidenote:

The linked article is wrong:

> The first theatrical movie to be shot above Earth's atmosphere, The Challenge, released its trailer.

Actually the first was a Soviet 1983 film released the following year, with full support of the state, called "Return from Orbit". It was shot by Cosmonauts in Soyuz T-9 and on the Salyut 7 space station.

[image]

[image]

A Soviet film featuring stoic characters, grief, tragedy and sadness..!

There was a short film, 'Apogee of Fear', filmed on the ISS in 2012 as well.

(NASA approved an official version a few years ago, also on youtube)

Comment: I meant to remove it actually but forgot. In fact the whole line was superfluous. Will modify it now actually.

Comment: Were those *theatrical* movies (actually screened in theaters)?

Comment: The short was shown at South by Southwest Film Festival; the Soviet film, yes.